# str_replace usando arrays

Tags: php, mysql, array, string

Quero negritar os termos pesquisados nos resultados, porém quando uso o `explode`, e tento usar no `str_replace`, recebo um *array* de volta.

```
<?php
$search_term = filter_var( $_GET['s'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

$palavras = explode( ' ', $search_term );

$q = 'SELECT * FROM classificados WHERE';
for ( $i = 0; $i < count($palavras); $i++ ) {
  $q.= " texto LIKE '%" . $palavras[$i] . "%' AND " ;
}
$q.= " aprovado='s' ORDER BY ID desc";

$r = mysql_query( $q );
if ( mysql_num_rows( $r )==0) //no result found
{
  echo "<div id='search-status'>Nenhum resultado encontrado!</div>";
}
else //result found
{
  echo "<ul>";

  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
  // aqui nao funciona
  $title = str_replace($palavras, "<b>". $palavras[$i] ."</b>", $row['texto']);
?>
```

A pesquisa funciona, pois, se busco "moto nova", retorna o texto, porém as palavras não são exibidas como quero.

Comment: Só pra constar, o mysql_* é (deprecated) a partir do PHP 5.5 e, as funções irão ser removidas nas novas versões do PHP.

Comment: e qual comando que vai substituir?

Comment: As alternativas são funções mysqli_ e o PDO (PHP Data Objects).
Há algum tempo teve um pergunta bem interessante e as respostas foram boas.
(http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que para usar o `str_replace` desta forma, você precisaria de duas *arrays*, uma com as palavras normais, e outra com as palavras já em negrito. Melhor seria um loop mesmo:

```
$title =  $row['texto'];
foreach( $palavras as $palavra ) {
    $title = str_ireplace( $palavra, '<b>' . $palavra . '</b>', $title );
}
```

Notar que usei o `str_ireplace`, assim a troca acontecerá independente da digitação ter sido com maiúsculas e minúsculas.

Se quiser maior performance com muitos resultados na listagem, pode fazer assim:

```
// acrescentar no topo
$palavras = explode( ' ', $search_term );
$negritos = $palavras;
array_walk( $negritos, function( &$neg ) { $neg = '<b>'.$neg.'</b>' } );

// e na parte do loop:
  echo "<ul>";
  while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r) ) {
     $title = str_ireplace( $palavras, $negritos, $row['texto'] );
  }
```

Comment: boa Bacco, achei que teria como fazer direto agora ficou bom

Answer (score 2):

Tente assim:

```
$palavras = explode( ' ', $search_term );
$palavrasnegrito = array();
foreach ($palavras as $p)
   $palavrasnegrito[] = "<strong>{$p}</strong>";



$title = str_replace($palavras, $palavrasnegrito, $row['texto']);
```