# Como posso substituir várias palavras sem usar STR_REPLACE?

Tags: php

Por exemplo, quero tirar palavrões de um texto.

Como posso fazer usando o método da substituição ? Algo que seja mais rápido.

Usar o `str_replace()` não é muito rápido.

Comment: Como assim não é rápido? Seria legal mostrar como você está fazendo, problema de velocidade pode ser no jeito de aplicar. o `str_replace` aceita _arrays_ inclusive, pode fazer várias substituições em uma linha só. Dei até exemplo aqui, inclusive do `str_ireplace`: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35562/str-replace-usando-arrays

Comment: Você pode utilizar o preg_replace() [PREG_REPLACE](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace.php) 
Em questão de desempenho não sei se faz muita diferença, mas é uma boa alternativa, cria o pattern e aplica sobre o texto, tudo depende da aplicação.

Comment: Eu posso usar array no `str_replace()` ?

Comment: @Zoom tem exemplo aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35562/str-replace-usando-arrays

Comment: @Zoom sim, o 1º e o 2º parâmetros podem ser array.

Comment: No Preg_Replace você pode utilizar arrays...

Comment: Pegando essa mesma ideia, posso fazer `highlights` para palavras pesquisadas ?

Comment: @FernandoA.W. mas ele quer algo mais rápido, nao mais lento.

Comment: @zoom `str_replace ( array( 'zoom', 'SOpt') , array( '<b>zoom</b>' , '<b>SOpt</b>' ), $texto )` assim vai trocar tudo que é zoom por **zoom** e tudo que é SOpt por **SOpt**.

Comment: Mas é aí que mora o problema. Para usar `array` no `str_replace`, tanto o `from` como o `to` tem que ser `array`. Não é ? O texto tem que ser convertido cada palavra em `array`.

Comment: @Zoom nao, o texto é string. Array sao as listas de originais e substitutas.

Comment: Certo. Entendi, crio um `array` com a lista de palavras feias e outra para palavras que quero que as substitua ou `####`.

Comment: `str_replace ( array( 'zoom', 'SOpt') , array( '<b>zoom</b>' , '<b>SOpt</b>' ), 'Eu sou o zoom do SOpt' )` vai virar `Eu sou o <b>zoom</b> do <b>SOpt</b>`

Comment: @Zoom nesse caso, pode por as feias como array, e do outro lado apenas '####' (assim todas virarão a mesma coisa). Aí voce usa array na busca, e string na substituta.

Comment: Beleza. Vou fazer isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar `preg_replace_callback()` ele é rápido.

No casso de querer substituir palavrões por '*' tem aqui um bom exemplo:

```
$badwords = array('bad1', 'bad2', 'bad3', 'ass');
$text = 'This is a test. Ass. Grass. bad1.';

function filterBadwords($text, array $badwords, $replaceChar = '*') {
    return preg_replace_callback(
        array_map(function($w) { return '/\b' . preg_quote($w, '/') . '\b/i'; }, $badwords),
        function($match) use ($replaceChar) { return str_repeat($replaceChar, strlen($match[0])); },
        $text
    );
}

echo filterBadwords($text, $badwords);
```

o echo ira imprimir:

> This is a test. ***. Grass. ****.

Se por outro lado em vez de substituir quiser realçar as palavras pode usar esta função:

```
$badwords = array('bad1', 'bad2', 'bad3', 'ass');
$text = 'This is a test. Ass. Grass. bad1.';

function badwords_filter($string,$badwords){
        $p = implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $words ));
        $string = preg_replace(
            '/('.$p.')/i', 
            '<span style="background:#fe5723; color:#fff">$1</span>', 
            $string
        );   
    return $string; 
}

echo badwords_filter($text, $badwords);
```